# How long does Postfix try to resend an email?

Tags: email, postfix

I have searched for answers to this question for some times now and I can't find any precise answer so I think it is good to ask it here:

How long will Postfix try to resend email to an unavailable server (for example a server which is off-line or there is no route to it)? And how can I change it?

Comment: Maximum queue lifetime seems to default to only 5 days (assuming I read this correctly: http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/mail_systems/postfix_documentation/TUNING_README_008.html). That seems rather short though. I am used to retreies up to 6 weeks.

Answer (score 2):

Postfix uses the [`maximal_queue_lifetime`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#maximal_queue_lifetime) configuration option to determine how long a message can stay in the queue and attempt delivery. It defaults to 5 days, but you can certainly change it.

The relevant standard, [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.5.4), in section 4.5.4.1, has this to say:

> Retries continue until the message is transmitted or the sender gives
> up; the give-up time generally needs to be at least 4-5 days.  It MAY
> be appropriate to set a shorter maximum number of retries for non-
> delivery notifications and equivalent error messages than for
> standard messages.  The parameters to the retry algorithm MUST be
> configurable.

That's presumably the source of defaulting to 5 days.